# How can I play an Aarakocra in 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, aarakocra

So we're 5 or 6 meets into my first d&d campaign (3.5e), and I'm really enjoying playing my 5th level elven druid. However, the chance that they die at the next meet is pretty high*.

I'm not too sad though, because I discovered the Aarakocra race. As a huge bird lover, I really really *really* want to play this race, probably as another druid or as a ranger. It's just a 5e race, though, so I'm looking for recommendations as to making an Aarakocra race in 3.5e- racial stat bonuses, abilities, and the like.

I've only ever made my druid (and that was with quite a bit of help), and I've only ever played 3.5e, so I wouldn't exactly call myself experienced xD. Thanks!

*I'm talking wild shape as an eagle flying over a pool of magma with an angry fire elemental that nobody knows how to fight throwing fireballs at me exclusively kind of chances.

Answer (score 16):

While, [as The Vagrant Dog’s answer notes, aarakocra are a “playable” race in 3.5e,](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122756/4563) that is almost a technicality: their LA +2 means you are allowed to play them under the rules, but that you basically never should. Level adjustment, if you are unfamiliar, means you count as a higher level (2 higher, in this case) without actually *being* higher level. In theory this is done because the race is more powerful than average (e.g. aarakocra can fly, which most races cannot and is a pretty big advantage), but ultimately it is almost never worth it. In fact, it’s almost-always **crippling**. LA means you have drastically fewer hp, far weaker saves, attacks, and skills, and you have fewer and weaker feats.

Instead, since you are a lover of birds, and not necessarily aarakocra in particular, I would point out the raptorans in *Races of the Wild*. These can only glide, not truly fly, until 5th level, but they are LA +0—meaning they are playable without any adjustment. That makes them **vastly** superior to aarakocra, and really, they’re a quite solid race. You will most likely fit in with your party far better, and have a much better time, playing a raptoran rather than an aarakocra.

In fact, in my games, if a player wants to play an aarakocra, my answer would be “OK... as long as you use the stats and rules for raptorans.”

Answer (score 9):

**You're in luck.**

Aarakocra are a playable race in 3.5, subject to your DM of course. They show up in the book *Races of Faerun,* though you can probably find them elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

### The Aarakocra have numerous versions available.

First appearing in AD&D (2e) in the Complete Book of Humanoids followed by an Athasian version in the 2e Dark Sun campaign setting, these avianoids have been around for a while.

There are official 3rd ed stats given in both the Forgotten Realms setting (mentioned in another answer) and in the official 3rd edition [Dark Sun](http://athas.org/products/ds3) material co-owned by Athas.org and WotC. The Athasian version is notably more user-friendly as it only has a +1 LA as opposed to the Forgotten Realms version which has a +2 LA modifier.

(The file named ds3_r7.pdf is the one you want; which is the latest official 3rd edition Dark Sun setting material available as the r8 is still under review. Pages 6-9 contain the Aarakocra racial notes. Like all material produced under the Athas-WotC agreement, it is free of charge.)

---

Found in the same book, the Pterrans are a pterodactyl-like humanoid, but the Athasian version does not have functional wings, only stubs, so would not meet the desire for flight.

Also found in the same book, the Athasian Thri-kreen used to be winged in a previous age, but lost them over the eras. However, there is a prestige class which can enable to Thri-kreen to undergo an atavistic evolution and regain the wings, though that is a lot of effort and levels just to gain flight.

Plus, psionics, which is almost always a win in my book. ^^

Answer (score -1):

3.5 has also has raptorans, which are similar to aarakocra, but aren't held back by LA. The tradeoff is that they don't get actual flight right off the bat.

Comment: This doesn't answer the bird lovers question for a bird race.

Comment: Could you explain what Raptorans are, and how they could solve the OPs problem?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. You may also want to review KRyan's existing answer, which seems to point this out already with relevant explanations.